# auto select shipping method from paypal review information page

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

please anyone suggest me how to auto select shipping method from paypal review page to review order page

In detail:

Basically, as customer order some product then he click on paypal checkout then after customer give paypal details and after that it redirects to paypal review Information page then after it redirects to my website www.example.com/paypal/express/review page where customer again select shipping method if he didn't select he is unable to place order as place order button was disabled
[image][image]

Comment: there is a option to skip the review in paypal payment method settings

Comment: i don't want to skip this page i want review page and in that i only want to auto select shipping method from paypal review information page

Comment: extend and develop a solution for auto-select then , only way out

Comment: Moreover it selects automatically shipping method in second time when customer click on edit shipping address or any other tab

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the template `default/template/paypal/express/review.phtml` to your theme and modify it.

**1. To just preselect a shipping method add at the end of the file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery("#shipping_method").val('flatrate_flatrate');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Where '`flatrate_flatrate`' is the shipping method value you want to preselect

**2. Tell the customer to select a shipping method [better solution]**

In my opinion a better solution is to tell the customer to select a shipping method.

Add a little hint above the "Place Order" button

```
<div id="missing_shipping_method" style="display:none; padding: 5px; color: #ff0000; float:right;">
    Please select a shipping method.
</div>
```

Add a little javascript snippet at the very end of the review.phtml to control the hint box and add/remove a red border from the select box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery('#shipping_method').change(function() {
        if (jQuery("#shipping_method").val() === "") {
            jQuery("#missing_shipping_method").show();
            jQuery("#shipping_method").css({
                'border': '2px solid',
                'border-color': '#ff0000'
            });
        } else {
            jQuery('#missing_shipping_method').hide();
            jQuery("#shipping_method").css({
                'border': '0px'
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#shipping_method').trigger('change');
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```